# Python, function in external file, globlal variable

Tags: python, function, global

For more organisation in my python project, I usually have 2 files:

- main.py, which has all the usefull code
- myfunction.py, which keep all the function

I keep the 2 files in the same folder, and at the beginning of main.py, I write `from myfunction import *`, so I can use use my fonction...

However, in one of my project, I need to access a global variable from within a function. So I use this

```
def mycoolfunction:
    global variable_i_need
    print( varaible_i_need)
```

But python doesn't access the `global` if the function is in another file like me.... Any idea to declare a global variable from within a function that in an external file ?

Comment: In general try not to use globals from another file.  Part of the reason of splitting-up code into different files is code reuse, but you can't reuse the code if it relies on globals being in another file.  Pass the global value as a parameter.